# Python/Selenium - Getting the element after an element

Tags: python, selenium, siblings

I need to close a popup window from the website itself by pressing the "X" window on the top right. Here is the shortened, relevant part of my code:

```
chromedriver = r'C:\Users\do\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url = 'Fake.com'

browser.get(url) 
browser.find_element_by_id('imgAttachmentsImg').click()
# I need to close out the window after this
```

The issue is that there are no unique identifiers for the "X" button itself. However, the pop up itself does have a unique identifier. I just need to be able to flow it down to the X button.

Info from the page:

```
1. V<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="attachmentsDialogOverview" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: auto; top: 239px; left: 102px; display: block;">
  2. <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
    3. <span id="ui-id-3" class="ui-dialog-title">Attachments</span>
   4. V<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
       5. <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"</span>
       6. <span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button>
```

I am new to using Python and Selenium. I switched over from VBA and still don't exactly understand all the syntax yet, so I do make mistakes! I did find a bandaid solution by just having sendkeys press Escape. But I am trying to actually understand how to actually solve this. I am not sure what errors I made with my solution:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id, 'ui-id-3']/following-sibling::button").click()
```

Questions

1. Why did my solution not work?
2. How would I locate "ui-id-3"(on line 3) and get to the element on Line 4 to click it?
3. How would I locate "ui-id-3"(on line 3) and get to the element on **Line 5** to click it? (just so I know how to move across multiple elements)

---

Relevant links I looked over:

[Following-Sibling Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127120/following-sibling-python-selenium)

[Find next sibling element in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887592/find-next-sibling-element-in-python-selenium)

[Using XPath Selector 'following-sibling::text()' in Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923721/using-xpath-selector-following-siblingtext-in-selenium-python)

[Python + Selenium WebDriver - Get div value if sibling contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948860/python-selenium-webdriver-get-div-value-if-sibling-contains-string)

[What is the correct syntax for using a variable and following-sibling in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697705/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-using-a-variable-and-following-sibling-in-python)

Comment: I doubt if this popup is in other frame, check for frame switching.

Comment: It is in the same frame. I switched over after I figured it out. I can interact with the other elements in the pop up right now (finally).

Comment: so, what sort of error do you get when you attempt to click on the close button?

Comment: If I attempt to use "browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id, 'ui-id-3']/following-sibling::button").click()", I get the following: "Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[@id, 'ui-id-3']/following-sibling::button because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[@id, 'ui-id-3']/following-sibling::button' is not a valid XPath expression."

Comment: So, you can try that xpath in your browser dev tool and see that it doesn't work.  Try //span[@id='ui-id-3']/following-sibling::button

Comment: @Breaks Software. The path works. It highlights the correct code(Line 4 here). Hmm. How would I go down to the next line? Maybe that would work?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xpath has a problem.  this should work:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='ui-id-3']/following-sibling::button").click()
```

To get to the span below it, you could use:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='ui-id-3']/following-sibling::button/span")
```

by the way, if you're more comfortable with CSS, the equivalent paths would be:

```
div#ui-id-3 > button
div#ui-id-3 > button span:nth-of-type(1)
```

Comment: THANK YOU. It worked and you explained everything(and more). The css addition is really nice too!. Just so I understand the CSS portion it would be something like this right...browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div#ui-id-3 > button span:nth-of-type(1)").click().    (Pretty sure that this is wrong)

Comment: actually, that ought to work...just that clicking on that span may not do much if there's no click event attached to the element.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this using the find_element() function:

```
##select an element
header = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//h5')[0]
## get the next link
header.find_element(By.XPATH, './/following-sibling::a').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```